# Building configuration DSL in Scala

Tags: scala, configuration, code-generation, typesafe

I want to turn Typesafe configuration

```
root {
  mainA = "test"
  submodule {
    paramA = "value"
    paramB = "value"
  }
  anotherModule {
    zoo = 1
    sub {
      z = test
    }
  }
}
```

into some sort of Scala configuration object like

```
object config {

  val cfg = ConfigFactory.load()

  val root = "root"

  lazy val mainA = cfg.getString("root.mainA")

  object submodule {
    lazy val paramA = cfg.getString("root.submodule.paramA","value")
    lazy val paramB = cfg.getString("root.submodule.paramB","value")
  }

  object anotherModule {
    lazy val zoo = cfg.getInt("root.anotherModule.zoo",1)
    object sub {
      lazy val z = cfg.getString("root.anotherModule.sub.z","test")
    }
  }
}
```

So in general I will have some "template" configuration file, and generate "Generic" 
configuration object with some defaults.

in Haskell I would use Template Haskell in order to generate and compile the code, 
what can I do about that in Scala?

Comment: You can use Scala 2.10's `def` macros to implement something like type providers, but it's a little tricky (see my blog posts [here](http://meta.plasm.us/posts/2013/06/19/macro-supported-dsls-for-schema-bindings/) and [here](http://meta.plasm.us/posts/2013/07/11/fake-type-providers-part-2/) for some examples and discussion). This will get a lot easier once we have [macro annotations](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/annotations.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to have a convenient way to use config from the Scala code, you may try to use `Dynamic` ancestor to access config. Something like:

```
class RichConfig(cfg:Config) extends Dynamic {
  private val `intClassTag` = implicitly[ClassTag[Int]]
  def selectDynamic[T](fieldName:String)(implicit ct:ClassTag[T]) = 
    ct match {
      case `intClassTag` =>
        cfg.getInt(fieldName)
    }
}
```

Of course it doesn't give you runtime check for existence of the configuration items.